# Update Custom user attribute using Rally User Management

Tags: ruby, rally

I have created a custom field for user in Rally called 'Info'. I have a excel which contains 2 columns userID and Info. I am trying to use the 'update_user_attributes.rb' ruby script from Rally User Management. But it seems to update only the Last name field and not the custom attribute Info. Kindly help me with this

Comment: Down voter, let me know why was it down voted? Give some information so that i can re-frame my question. There is no use in just do voting just for the sake of it.

Comment: Show some code please

Comment: @papirtiger wow, Do you even read the question?

Comment: @DDK, I find sometimes it helps to reference the github repo for the toolkit being used when asking similar questions in SO. While Rally users may be familiar with the update_user_attributes.rb script, most Ruby experts won't be, which can cause confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The update_user_attributes.rb script only includes a select list of extended User Attributes, since it currently doesn't poll for and handle any/all Subscription-Specific Custom Fields for the User Object (these will vary from customer to customer, or subscription to subscription).

[This Gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/11373647) contains a custom version of update_user_attributes.rb that adds a handler for an Info field that is at Column 14 of an input tab-delimited text file. You may use it in replacement of the [default update_user_attributes.rb](https://github.com/RallyTools/Rally-User-Management/blob/master/update_user_attributes.rb) script. It will populate the content from Column 14 into a custom field called "Info" that must exist on the User Object (if it doesn't, the customized updater script will fail).

You may wish to file a [GitHub Issue for the User Mgmt Toolkit](https://github.com/RallyTools/Rally-User-Management/issues) to request an enhancement to allow for configuration of a user-specified list of Custom Fields on Users.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was able to change the lastName to Info and was able to update the custom field `if !last_name_field.nil? then
    last_name = last_name_field.strip
    user_fields["Info"] = last_name`